# Woocommerce add default shipping class to all products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, shopping-cart

Is there a way to add a default shipping class to all products? I have one shipping class and need an automated way to add that class to all products when they are created vs. having to constantly add the shipping class.

Answer (score 1):

Many solutions

There is two solutions :

First add the term dynamically before the cart totals (add to your functions.php)

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' , 'add_shipping_terms_before_totals' , 10, 1);

function add_shipping_terms_before_totals(WC_Cart $wc_cart){

    if( count($wc_cart->get_cart()) == 0 ){
        return;
    }

    // Here you need to edit the slug_to_edit with your custom slug
    $shipping_terms = get_term_by( 'slug', 'slug_to_edit', 'product_shipping_class' );

    // If can't find the terms, return
    if( empty($shipping_terms) ){
        return;
    }


    foreach( $wc_cart->get_cart() as $item){
        $product = new WC_Product( $item['product_id'] );

        $product_shipping_class = $product->get_shipping_class();

        if( !empty($product_shipping_class) ){
            continue;
        }

        wp_set_post_terms( $product->id, array( $shipping_terms->term_id ), 'product_shipping_class' );
    }

}
```

Or, you can add a function that you can manually trigger when you add a products :

```
if( isset($_GET['update_products']) && is_super_admin() ){
    add_action( 'init', 'add_shipping_terms_on_all_products' );
}

function add_shipping_terms_on_all_products(){
    global $wpdb;

    // Here you need to edit the slug_to_edit with your custom slug
    $shipping_terms = get_term_by( 'slug', 'slug_to_edit', 'product_shipping_class' );

    // If can't find the terms, return
    if( empty($shipping_terms) ){
        return;
    }

    // Request all product
    $products = $wpdb->get_results( "
        SELECT p.ID as ID
        FROM wp_posts AS p
        WHERE p.post_status   = 'publish'
        AND p.post_type     = 'product'
        " );

    foreach($products as $_product){
        $product = new WC_Product($_product->ID);

        $product_shipping_class = $product->get_shipping_class();

        if( !empty($product_shipping_class) ){
            continue;
        }

        wp_set_post_terms( $product->id, array( $shipping_terms->term_id ), 'product_shipping_class' );
    }

}
```

Then you just have to trigger :

```
 http://yoururl?update_products
```

as admin.

Don't forget to edit slug_to_edit with your shipping class slug

Comment: My slug is 'Shipping'; for the solution #1 I edited `slug_to_edit` and nothing happened. For solution #2 my site wouldn't load with the provided code, it was just blank. Do I have to trigger that URL for both solutions? When I did it redirected to `http://myurl/?update_products`